# The way of JMeter Result Analysis

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

No Of Requests - 2113 ;

Average Response time  (s) - 123.5 ;

Response time/Sec (90% of  Requests) - 142.9

Minimum Response time  (s) - 2.4

Maximum response time (s) - 14.9

Error% -0.0

My Questions  - For 2113 requests average response time is 123.5 secs I need to know what will be the response time of average one single request in 2113 requests

Answer (score 1):

The average response time of a single request (1 out of 2,113) will be the value itself, but I'm sure this isn't your question.

Are you simply trying to locate the response time of each request after a given test plan has fully executed, that is, to see each of the 2,113 response times? If so, just add a [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) to your thread group. By doing this you'll need to specify an output file (which will get generated if it doesn't already exist) and will show you in detail each of the requests sent to the server, along with the HTTP response code, response time and other goodies.

**UPDATE**

Per the question posed in the comments via Ripon Al Wasim, the default extension of the results file is CSV, however this is configurable in /bin/jmeter.properties:

```
# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

As we can see, JMeter only appears to support XML and CSV.

Comment: By doing this you'll need to specify an output file (which will get generated if it doesn't already exist): What's the extension of this file?

Comment: Updated the answer per the question above from @RiponAlWasim